# Tooltip on Polyline (Route) Hover

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've made ​​the route on the map. The route generated using some coordinates which completed with additional information (speed). I want when the route is hover, a tooltip will appear and showing information (speed) at those coordinates. I confuse how to display the tooltip of speed.

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Polyline Route v3 Example</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>   
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
        {"speed":"13","lat":"-6.246192976751192","lon":"106.79324626922607"}, {"speed":"33","lat":"-6.245723710157699","lon":"106.79603576660156"}, {"speed":"23","lat":"-6.245723710157699","lon":"106.79796695709229"}, {"speed":"43","lat":"-6.243334710069922","lon":"106.79800987243652"},
        {"speed":"12","lat":"-6.245723810157699","lon":"106.79796725709229"}, {"speed":"1","lat":"-6.245723860157699","lon":"106.79796735709229"}, {"speed":"45","lat":"-6.245723890157699","lon":"106.79797755709229"}, {"speed":"21","lat":"-6.245723910157699","lon":"106.79797895709229"}
    ];
    var map;
    function createRouteMap(){
    var listRoute = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        listRoute.push(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lon));
    }
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: listRoute[Math.ceil(listRoute.length/2)],
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    showMap(listRoute);
    createMarkers(locations);
}

function showMap(listRoute){
    if((listRoute.length < 1) || (listRoute == null)){
        jQuery("#map_canvas").html('<div class="alert alert-info"> <strong>Empty Trail!</strong> This trip still has no trail </div>'+
        '<div class="btn-toolbar"> <p><code>The gps device </code>in the car still not sent position!</p> </div>');
    }else{
        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: listRoute,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 5,
            strokeWeight: 3.7
        });
        flightPath.setMap(map);
    }
}

function createMarkers(locations) {
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var point = locations[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lon);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: 'greencirclemarker.png',
            title: point.speed
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    createRouteMap();
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:400px; border:1px 00f solid;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "speeds" are associated with points.  You have a couple of options:

1. add markers and display the speed on mouseover of the marker (or as a tooltip of the marker)
2. render each segment of the line as a separate polyline with its own mouseover event handler. You will need to specify how to apply the speeds to the line segments.  There are more complicated ways to do it with a single polyline, but with a mouseover event may have performance issues.

Comment: for first option, if it mean that i must create marker as number of point? I mean, if I have 10 points, than i must create 10 markers.Is it like that?

Comment: Yes.  That seems the simplest (since the speeds are associated with those).

Comment: Thank's Mr geocodezip, it works. I have edit my question and have inserting the right code.

Comment: When i have about 25.000 points (coordinate), it will very slow to show the map. How can i make it faster?
Or maybe it's better to create new thread for this question?

Comment: That is another question. For 25000 points you probably want to render the line on tiles (either on your server or using KmlLayer or FusionTablesLayer which render as tiles), the issue will be creating the mouseover handler, which will be more complicated in that case.  See [Too Many Markers!](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers) from the "articles" section of the documentation.