# Handling large amount marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In this case, i want to display log route of an a car. I have create polyline (flightPath) to display the route. And because I also want to know speed of car in certain position (coordinate), I also have create marker on the route.
This is my code (question) before [Tooltip on Polyline (Route) Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429680/tooltip-on-polyline-route-hover). The problem is when the numbers of marker is very large (bulk). The route will displayed slowly. Mr geocodezip has give me a reference on that thread ([Too Many Markers!](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers)).

- Grid-based Clustering
- Distance-based Clustering
- Viewport Marker Management
- Flash
- Fusion Tables
- MarkerClusterer
- MarkerManager

But I confuse what solution is the best one for this case. I think Distance-based Clustering or maybe MarkerManager is suitable for this case, but I am doubt maybe another is better. And I want to ask about that, what is the best way to handle this. MarkerClusterer? Fusion Tables? or maybe another library? Thank you.